# Python Dataframe Rounding Issue

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python 2.7 and I have data in a dataframe (`df`) and when I try rounding it does not consistently round. Based on search I found code to use `Decimal().quantize()` to attempt this, but have hit a wall on figuring out the error that it throws.

`df` has `value1` with values `0.121` to `0.130` I am testing on.

My code:

`Decimal((df['value1'])).quantize(Decimal("0.01"), decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)`

Error I get is:

> raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)

I also see TypeError as:

> TypeError: Cannot convert 0    0.121

Any help is appreciated as this has frustrated me for a couple days. I am new to Python, so I might be missing something simple.

Comment: `df['value1'].round(2)` will round any value to 2 decimal places. 0.121 >> 0.12

Comment: Khalil Al Hooti,I had used that, but 0.125 rounded to 0.12 and not 0.13.

Comment: try then `np.around(df['value'], decimals=2)`

Comment: actually pandas round is working fine for me. >>>`a = pd.Series([1.225, 0.135])` >>>`a.round(2)` gives `1.23` and `0.14`.

Comment: Let me add that when I check the data type of my value1, that it is float. The reason I was converting to decimal was to get rid of any issues with float. Using .round(2) and the np.around(..., decimals=2) does not accurately round on the float I have in my dataframe. 0.125 always rounds to 0.12 using these two methods.

Comment: you might want to read about floating point representation of numbers in a modern computer https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html  and also here for more detail http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf

Comment: I have always been told floats are bad and they will cause issues. What I would like an answer for is why using Decimal() is throwing an error.